# How fine a control can Big Bertha exert over her weight?

Tags: comics, marvel, powers, avengers

Big bertha is a member of the Great Lakes Avengers (GLA) who by day is Ashley Crawford, supermodel. By night (and sometimes day) she is Big Bertha.

[image]

Her powers allow her to gain weight, granting her superhuman endurance and strength. Normally however we see the amount of weight she gains is huge, and I was interested in knowing if she has any control over the amount of weight she gains, or if it's an all or nothing power.

Comment: Wow, talk about your politically incorrect superheroes....

Comment: If you read the comics you'll see she's actually got a very PC attitude of "It's what on the inside that counts"

Comment: ...and still chooses to look like a supermodel.

Comment: @ianpugsly that's just how she 'normally' looks, as far as I know. I don't know if she has an in-between. Thus this question

Comment: @IanPugsley that's whats on the inside of the gigantic woman she turns into...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the description from the [Marvel Wiki](http://marvel.wikia.com/Ashley_Crawford_%28Earth-616%29) entry:

> Ashley Crawford is a mutant with the primary ability to alter the height and mass of her body by a tremendous degree. When she uses her powers, she gains an additional 15 inches in height and adds approximately 630 lbs of tissue to her frame.

It sounds like it is an all or nothing thing. It doesn't say she can add *up to* 630 lbs of tissue, just that she *does* add that much. This suggestions to me she is either a super model, or a Big Bertha.

**Bonus**

Most disturbing thing about this super hero?

> When she wishes to return to her normal form, Bertha has to make herself throw up.

Yikes.